# Angular Directives in Html helper

Tags: c#, html, angularjs-directive, razorengine

How to include `Angular directives` in `Html Helper` in ASP.NET MVC C#.
I dont know how to include it.
What I have done is following :

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Questions.Question , new{ng_model="quest"})
                    {{quest}}
```

But when I look for source code that does not have `ng-model directive`?

Answer (score 2):

The second Argument of Html.EditorFor is for the extended ViewData.
It is used by the template. The Default template dont use your additional entries.
But it supports htmlAttributes

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Questions.Question , new { htmlAttributes = new { ng_model="quest" }})
```

or render it with out any template

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Questions.Question, new { ng_model = "quest" })
```

Comment: Your solution adding the htmlAttributes option didn't work. if I use your second idea of removing the template it shows the _ng-model_ directive. Any ideas why?

Comment: the first method with EditorFor gives the htmlAttributes in the additionalViewData argument. If u are using a custom EditorFor template u need to pass the htmlAttributes again to the next call/template

In your custom editor template like:
@Html.TextBox("", Model.Value, ViewData["htmlAttributes"])

Answer (score 0):

To include Angular directives in Html Helper you should pass a null parameter as a second then pass the angular directive in a object.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ViewBag-Name", null, new { ng_model = "Model-Name"})
```

Where ViewBag-Name contains a SelectList object pass to the view from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it very easily.

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @ng_change = "call()" ,@class="form-control" }})
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.TextBox("Text1", null, new { ng_model = "model1" })